# SSIS keeps the RAM memory blocked after the package execution gets completed

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, etl, ram

I have the 28GB RAM. I am also running the SSIS package to integrate 3M rows. And, I have allocated the 21GB memory to SQL Server

**During SSIS Package Execution**

- **SQL Server Windows NT - 64 Bit** service starts eating the RAM up to 21GB that has allocated to the SQL Server.

**After SSIS Package Execution**

- Once SSIS package execution gets completed, the process **SQL Server Windows NT - 64 Bit** does not release the memory and keeps showing 21GB RAM in use until I manually restart the SQL Server service from SQL Server Configuration Manager

Why SSIS is not releasing the memory?
And, How to release the memory once SSIS completes the package execution?

Comment: There's no leak or problem. Database servers use their memory for caching and never release it. That's by desing - the machine exists to serve databases after all. If you want your server to use less RAM set a maximum RAM size. But as you say, you already did, and the server is doing what you told it to do

Comment: Don't restart the server. There's nothing wrong with it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Thanks!

Comment: Pedantic point, SSIS spins up, does the work and terminates returning its memory to the server. All of this is outside of SQL Server's memory space which as the duplicate reference indicates is by design.